# При вводе русских букв в виджет add_input_text в DearPyGui виджет принимает на вход другие буквы (латинские)

Tags: python-3.x, кодировка, кириллица, dearpygui

Пишу приложение на DearPyGui и во время ввода текста в строку ввода не отображаются русские символы. Вместо них отображаются латинские.

```
b2 = dpg.add_input_text(tag = "input", hint="Введите имя и фамилию", width=465, callback=_log)
dpg.bind_item_font(b2, small_font)
```

[image: вывод в консоль введенных символов]

```
def _log(sender, app_data, user_data):
    print(f"sender: {sender}, \t app_data: {app_data}, \t user_data: {user_data}")
```

Решил проблему с отображением на экране в самой строке ввода через dpg.add_char_remap()
Однако это исправило только визуальную отрисовку. По факту в app_data передаются всё те же символы, что указаны на скриншоте. "vfdvóììö"

Я бы не заморачивался, если бы add_data не записывалась в JSON файл, и там уже начинаются проблемы, потому что он не понимает эти символы, хоть по факту на клаве и ввожу русские буквы.

PS: кодировка UTF-8, уже проверил, а шрифт поддерживает кириллицу, и в font_registry() это явно указал. Ничего из этого не помогает.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй поставить шрифт для кириллицы самостоятельно

```
with dpg.font_registry():
    with dpg.font("./LiteralRegular.otf", 18, default_font=True, tag="Default font") as f:
        dpg.add_font_range_hint(dpg.mvFontRangeHint_Cyrillic)
```

P.S. Не забудь скачать этот LiteralRegular и поместить его в папку